# Android :IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android

I'm getting same error in my whole activity where is my cursor code of IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase. Here is my code.I don't understand wheres the code is going wrong. Thanks in advanved.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from ActivityObjectList where activityId " + "= ? ", new String[]{strListItem_ActivityId});
                imageArray.clear();
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imageaudioPath"));
                        imageArray.add(imagePath);
                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
```

Here is code in onCreate() method.

```
dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(this);
            dbhelper.onOpen(db);
            db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Here is my log cat error

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.example.tazeen.classnkk/databases/ClassNKK
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1312)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$MyListAdapter.getView(AllPosts_Page.java:1245)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2150)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15595)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:562)
```

Comment: Put `dbhelper.onOpen(db);
            db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();` these two lines before declaring **Cursor**.

Comment: Or, if it's just a query (SELECT) and not a command, you can use `dbhelper.onOpen(db); db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();` - You don't need the database to be writable, in case of queries.